# F# Incomplete Structured Construct Caused By Type Specification

Tags: f#

So, I have a function, `corners`, that I want to take a 2D array (with abbreviated type HieghtMap) and return a list of the record type of Coordinates. Initially, I wasn't specifying matrixLocal's type, which led to 
`System.Exception: Operation could not be completed due to earlier error
 The type 'matrixLocal' is not defined. at 30,28`

Now that I am specifying the type, I get this new error

```
 Syntax error in labelled type argument at 30,39 
 Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in
 interaction. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before
 this point, ';', ';;' or other token.
```

I believe this is due to `farside` (as it does not function even on its own), but I do not know why, hence I am here. The other questions that I found regarding the latter error do not seem to apply in this case (one was about indenting, and the other was about trying to redefine a variable in a loop).

The Code:

```
module DiamondSquare =

//create type for defining shapes
///Defined by length of the side of a square that the ovject is inscribed in
type Shape =
    | Square of int
    | Diamond of int

///the X and Y position
type Coordinates = {X: int; Y: int}

///The Hieghtmap of a given chunk of region as a series of floats that are the offset from the base hieght
//was HieghtMap = HieghtMap of float[,], but was changed so that any 2D float array would be accepted
type HieghtMap = float[,]

//Create matrix of zeroes of chunk size to initilize this variable
let matrix = Array2D.zeroCreate<float> 9 9

//locate center of shape
//  since each shape is a square, or can be inscribed within one, pass it a matrix and find the
//  coordinate of the center (same value for i and j)
///Finds center of shape inscribed within a square. Takes a matrix, returns coordinates for within the matrix
let locateCenterpoint matrixLocal = 
    let coord = int ((Array2D.length1 matrixLocal) - 1) / 2
    {X = coord; Y = coord;}

//locate corners of a shape that is inscribed in a square
///Returns list of corner values for a given shape. Takes a matrix and returns a list of Coordinates
let corners shape:Shape matrixLocal:HieghtMap =
    let farSide = Array2D.length1 matrixLocal - 1
    let getSquareCorners = 
        {X = 0; Y = 0}::{X = farSide; Y = 0}::{X = 0; Y = farSide}::{X = farSide; Y = farSide}::[]
    let getDiamondCorners =
        {X = farSide / 2; Y = 0}::{X = farSide; Y = farSide / 2}::{X = farSide / 2; Y = farSide}::{X = 0; Y = farSide / 2}::[]
    match shape with
    | Square -> getSquareCorners
    | Diamond -> getDiamondCorners
    | _ -> None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining a value in F#, the first colon signifies the end of value names and start of the type declaration. For example:

```
let f x y : string = ...
```

In this declaration, `string` is the return type of the function, and *not* type of the `y` parameter. In order to apply type declaration to a single value in the list, use parentheses:

```
let f x (y: string) = ...
```

This way, `string` is the type of `y`.

For your specific case, look at this line:

```
let corners shape:Shape matrixLocal:HieghtMap =
```

See what the problem is? `Shape` is being parsed as the return type of the `corners` function, and this makes the subsequent `matrixLocal:HeightMap` nonsensical. To fix, apply parentheses:

```
let corners (shape:Shape) (matrixLocal:HieghtMap) =
```

Comment: Thank you very much! for single input functions, should I also be using parentheses to be specifying types?

Comment: Yes. Regardless of the number of parameters, a type specification without parentheses will always mean the function return type.